# Set color of a specific bullet in a list

Tags: html, css, list

I have this CSS:

```
 .list-mark-3 li:before {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    content: '\f101';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white !important;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <ul class="list list-mark-3">
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li class="makeitwhite">DEF</li>
        <li>GHI</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

which produces something like this:

[image]

However, I would like to make the bullet, and the text for that matter, for DEF white. Just that one bullet. I have tried setting the color to white in the "makeitwhite" class, inline style, etc. Nothing!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want DEF to be white on `hover` or always white?

Comment: @Bodrov Always white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
.list-mark-3 li.makeitwhite
    {
        color:white;
    }
```

Comment: Close enough to give me the idea for:

.list-mark-3 li.whitebullet:before {
    color: white !important;
    content: '\f101';
}

So mark as answer. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `nth-child()` for that:

```
.list-mark-3 li:before {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    content: '\f101';
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white !important;
}

.list-mark-3 li:nth-child(2) {
    color: white;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmgaLpb7/)

To make it white on `hover`, add this: `li:nth-child(2):hover`

Comment: I don't know the position of the item since the list is filled from a database. So I can't use position based style. Need to be able to add a class, or inline style, to <li> directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the in-line css

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <ul class="list list-mark-3">
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li style="color: white;">DEF</li>
        <li>GHI</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the TEXT white, but not the bullet itself.